# How to include database schema and data in setup and deployment of asp.net web application?

Tags: asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to deploy my web application created with asp.net in visual studio 2010. I have successfully created .exe and .msi file, install it and run using IIS Manager. However, it needs a database which is why it is returning

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'TableName', database 'master', schema 'dbo'.
```

whenerver I try to run it on browser with localhost.

How do I include my database file in deployment so that when I install my application in another computer, the database will also be created?

Answer (score 2):

It is not at all clear what exactly you mean by database file but if you are referring to an SQLLite or SQL Server CE database file all you have to do is go to properties and change the "Copy to Output Directory" property to "Copy if Newer" (don't forget to do the same with the required class libraries).

If you are referring to SQL Server, Oracle or some other RDBMS database than you can't just copy the file, you'd have to either use DDL to create the database or attach the database file using the SSMS.

EDIT: I did not pay attention to the exception you posted so the second part of my question is relevant. SQL Server database file cannot be just copied to another computer, the target computer must have the SQL Server installed and you must detach the file from your local SQL Server and attach it on the remote SQL Server using the SQL Server Management Studio.